# phonegap - Playing html5 audio from local ressource

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, audio, howler.js

I have build a simple demo app that should play a locally stored mp3-file (delivered as part of the app). I want to use html5-audio instead of phonegap's Media-Object. I am using the howler.js framework to get somewhat better performance.

The local file is stored under `www/res/audio/2.mp3`.

Everything works fine when running it on my desktop browser. However, I cannot get it to work when deployed to my android device. The weired thing is: The playback of a remotely hosted mp3-file works just peachy, thus I assume that something is wrong with url(s) I use with my local file. I have tried different url-"versions", but none of the below works:

```
www/res/audio/2.mp3
/android_asset/www/res/audio/2.mp3
file:///android_asset/www/res/audio/2.mp3
file://android_asset/www/res/audio/2.mp3

http://audio.ibeat.org/content/p1rj1s/p1rj1s_-_rockGuitar.mp3 //works great
```

It drives me crazy. Any ideas how to get it to work and what my mistake is? Please see my code below or [download my entire code here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/34209136/2014-08-18%20phonegap%20html5audio%20test.zip).

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.css" />

    <title>Audio-Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- ------------- -->
    <!-- Script import -->    
    <script src="js/libs/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/libs/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/libs/howler/howler.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/index.js"></script>

    <!-- ---------- -->
    <!-- Start Page -->

    <div id="index" data-role="page" data-theme="a">
      <!-- HEADER, FOOTER -->
      <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
      <h1>Audio-Tester</h1>
      </div>

      <!-- CONTENT -->
      <div class="ui-content">
        <h1 id='ready' style='text-align: center;'></h1>

        <select id='urls'></select>
        <button id='playSelected'>Play audio from selected source!</button>

        <div id='log'></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- ------------- -->
    <!-- Init Phonegap -->
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad|Android|BlackBerry|IEMobile)/)) {
          isPhonegap = true;

          $.getScript( 'cordova.js', function() {
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
            app.initialize();
          });
        } 
        else {
          //Fallback for desktop browsers!
          isPhonegap = false;
          onDeviceReady();
        }
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```
function onDeviceReady() {
  $('#ready').html("I'm ready!");

  //populate selection
  var basePath = getBasePath();
  var audioUrl = 'res/audio/2.mp3';

  var myOptions = {
      val1 : 'http://audio.ibeat.org/content/p1rj1s/p1rj1s_-_rockGuitar.mp3',
      val2 : audioUrl,
      val3 : basePath + audioUrl,
      val4 : 'file://' + basePath + audioUrl,
      val5 : 'file:/' + basePath + audioUrl
  };

  var urls = $('#urls');
  $.each(myOptions, function(val, text) {
      urls.append(
          $('<option></option>').val(val).html(text)
      );
  });

  //append listener to button
  $('#playSelected').click(function() {
    var myHowl = new Howl({ urls: [$('#urls option:selected').text()] });
    myHowl.play();

    $('#log').html($('#log').html() + '<br /> Playing ' + myHowl.urls());
  });
}

function getBasePath() {
  var htmlFilename = 'index.html';
  var path = window.location.pathname;
  path = path.substr(0, path.length - htmlFilename.length);

  return path;
}
```

Comment: did you solve this issue ? I'm running into the same #howlerjs + #phonegap wall. I made tests on my side, I also downloaded a version of your code, but I didn't found the way.

Comment: Unfortunately not! There seems to be a bug/"feature" in android's browser that prevents html5-autio from playing...

Comment: Oh god. My full project is based on web apps dev > audio > howlerJS > code copy > Phonegap. Did you move to a switch for phonegap media plugin and `var media = new Media(your_audioUrl);media.play();` as I may do ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mL5qtdc6/1/))? What is the solution you enventually took.

Comment: I asked on howlerjs github, seems there is hope. https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js/issues/224

Comment: seems it may be due to mp3, tried ogg ? Could you provide again your seed on github or dropbox, so the community may do further tests.

Answer (score 0):

This code is working in phonegap.

```
  <body>

     <audio controls>
     <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
     Your browser does not support the audio element.
     </audio>

 </body>
```

Comment: Are you sure this works works on Android? As far as my research led me it seems that Android Web View has a problem with all html5-audio!

Comment: it's working in ios. i did not test on android. but in IOS working fine.

Comment: yeah, then the problem stays: howler.js uses html5-audio internally, too.

Comment: I think you should use Phonegap plugin and it will work in both android and IOS    http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_media_media.md.html#Media

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#playSelected').click(function() {
   var media = new Media(your_audioUrl);
   media.play();
}
```

Comment: As I stated above, I do not want to use Media-object!